# VS Code Powershell Switch User

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I am working in visual studio code for Powershell 7. (Finally took the dive) However, I need to run code as another user, Normally to do this, enter a new pssession on my computer. This creates something like sudo su. However, I am getting an error message stating access is denied.

code:

```
New-PSSession -Credential (Get-Credential) | Enter-PSSession
```

Error message:

> New-PSSession : [localhost] Connecting to remote server localhost failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I oftentimes work under a special system admin account.

----- Update 3/31/2020 @ 4:06pm -----
After working on enabling PS remoting, I was able to run the following code:

```
New-PSSession -computername (Test-Connection -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -Count 1).IPV4address.ipaddresstostring -Credential (Get-Credential) | Enter-PSSession
```

This allowed me to switch user in a basic powershell prompt, but not inside vscode. VS code is still giving me the same access denied error code.

Comment: MSFT shipped a Windows update in February last year, after which WinRM won't create loopback sessions for non-admin accounts (due to an otherwise unspecified privilege escalation vuln). So start there: is the (target) account a member of the builtin Administrators group on the machine?

Comment: Yes, the target account and the account running are both in the built-in administrators group on the machine.

Comment: In that case I'd have a look at the Security event log on the system to see why the logon failed :)

Comment: I have been searching the logs. Do you have an idea where to look?